# libncursesw.so.5 is installed but a program that needs it says "No such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to run a program as such:

```
 ~/junk/cataclysmdda-0.E$ ./cataclysm
```

which returns

```
error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried a few things like, `sudo apt-get install libncurses5` with no luck.
If I search for libncurses.so.5 in my system I find 3 of them in different parts of the /snap directory. Maybe the program is not looking there? If so I don't no how to fix that.
I also found this advice:

```
root@examplehost ~]# ln -s /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.6.1 /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5
```

So using that I tried to link one of the libncurses.so.5 files in /usr/lib/ and when that didn't work in /usr/lib64/ (I thought that was logical but I don't have a clue), still no luck.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any other information that i can add. I still feel like its not being shared because it was installed in the snap directory. But i dont know how to change this.

Answer (score 7):

> sudo apt-get install libncursesw5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).